# How to stop jquery event while working on countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

I hardly have knowledge of jquery. I am trying to make a countdown so after searching I found the code below.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
    
}
$('.start').on('click', function(){
    var oneMinute = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(oneMinute, display);
})
```

But the countdown repeats after one minute. Like when it goes 03, 02, 01, it again starts with 59.

How to stop it?

I want to alert message and stop timer after given minutes.

Comment: I don’t get how people on this platform try and use “I have hardly any knowledge” or “I am new to this” as an excuse for not really making an effort, all day long. We are not here to fix “found” code for y’all. If _you_ want to use this code, then _you_ should make an effort to try and understand how it works. jQuery has good documentation, so you can go and _read up_ on stuff like this.

Comment: The problem is `if (--timer < 0) { timer = duration; }`, just place `alert("Time stopped");` to check changes

Comment: @CBroe I only know the basic like onclick, selector. I am not using this platform to make other developers fix my issues. I tried to doing `if(timer == -1){ return false; }` and since I did not wrote this code I got more confused. You cannot tell if someone is putting effort or not just by reading there word to express their problem. Thank you for your opinion, though.

Comment: If you actually tried anything, then please mention that in your question right away. _“You cannot tell if someone is putting effort or not just by reading there word to express there problem.”_ - and that is exactly why you should do more, than _just_ express the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval` function returns an identifier. Store the interval ID in a variable. This allows you to use `clearInterval()` to cancel the interval when required.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        
    }, 1000);
    
}
$('.start').on('click', function(){
    var oneMinute = 5 * 1, // 5 Seconds for easy testing
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(oneMinute, display);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="time">
00:00
</div>

<button type="button" class="start">
START
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the interval ID and use `clearInterval(intervalId);` to stop it.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 1000);
    
}

$('.start').on('click', function(){
    var oneMinute = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(oneMinute, display);
})
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. But, can only vote one. Someone has already voted your answer as well so cheers! Thanks :-)